# How to combine akka stream source queue with graph?

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I have a queue need to be  broadcasted and merged using akka stream graphs.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8T0Qh.png)

I found the graph demo and queue demo. and don't know how to **combine them**. Can anyone help me out? Thanks

**Here is the graph demo**

```
val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder: 
GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._
  val in = Source(1 to 10)
  val out = Sink.ignore

  val bcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Int](2))
  val merge = builder.add(Merge[Int](2))

  val f1, f2, f3, f4 = Flow[Int].map(_ + 10)

  in ~> f1 ~> bcast ~> f2 ~> merge ~> f3 ~> out
  bcast ~> f4 ~> merge
  ClosedShape
})
```

**And here is the Queue Demo**

```
val bufferSize = 5
val elementsToProcess = 3

val queue = Source
  .queue[Int](bufferSize, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
  .throttle(elementsToProcess, 3.second)
  .map(x ⇒ x * x)
  .toMat(Sink.foreach(x ⇒ println(s"completed $x")))(Keep.left)
  .run()

val source = Source(1 to 10)

implicit val ec = system.dispatcher
source.mapAsync(1)(x ⇒ {
  queue.offer(x).map {
    case QueueOfferResult.Enqueued    ⇒ println(s"enqueued $x")
    case QueueOfferResult.Dropped     ⇒ println(s"dropped $x")
    case QueueOfferResult.Failure(ex) ⇒ println(s"Offer failed 
${ex.getMessage}")
    case QueueOfferResult.QueueClosed ⇒ println("Source Queue closed")
  }
}).runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

I want to run a graph that return a queue,so that I can offer element to it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `val queue` is the result of the "queue" (which became a `RunnableGraph` via the `toMat` combinator) being run. Your `g` is also a `RunnableGraph` (which you can call run on). *Offering an element* to such a graph means defining a `Source` which passes elements downstream. What you can combine are the different components making up such a runnable graph. It requires a `Source` and a `Sink` and may have an arbitrary amount of `Flow` components in between. I'd suggest you go through [the official documentation for akka streams](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/) in order to understand how they work in general and look at the custom graphs section in particular.